# Redundant connection between modelling views in SAP HANA metadata

Tags: view, model, metadata, hana

Background: I am making a small documentation tool for SAP HANA. Extracting Meta data and visualize them using D3.js. So far I am almost done (about 10 days of work)

I use the **Table_SYS_REPO.ACTIVE_OBJECTCROSSREF** to retrieve **how views are connected to each other**. This works very good in most cases.

For each calculation view I get a list of views / tables which are directly used by the view to document. (So I recursively create new SQL - Statements until no more childs are retrieved.)

In some cases however the result contains an additional entry with an underlying Table which is not directly connected to the view.

Example:

```
;FROM_PACKAGE_ID ;FROM_OBJECT_NAME;FROM_OBJECT_SUFFIX;TO_TENANT_ID;TO_PACKAGE_ID ;TO_OBJECT_NAME ;TO_OBJECT_SUFFIX ;SRC_PATH;DST_PATH;REF_TYPE
1 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;SAPABAP1 ;CUANC_CLNTMAP ;__RT_CATALOG_TABLE__; ; ;0
2 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.edwh ;CA_VTRG_PEB_PROD_FAM ;calculationview ; ; ;0
3 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.relation ;CA_GBEZ_PART_VTRG ;calculationview ; ; ;0
4 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.det;CA_VTRG_NL_AGGR_POL ;calculationview ; ; ;0
5 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.det;CA_VTRG_NL_VS_HR ;calculationview ; ; ;0
6 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.pol;CA_VTRG_NL_BASIS ;calculationview ; ; ;0
7 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.pol;CA_VTRG_NL_LTZTE_MAN_MUTN ;calculationview ; ; ;0
8 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.pol;CA_VTRG_NL_LTZTE_MAN_MUTN_EXKL_ONLINE;calculationview ; ; ;0
9 ;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.pol;CA_VTRG_NL_MAX_DAT_NEUGESCH ;calculationview ; ; ;0
10;comp.operativ.segm.seg_bol;CA_VTRG_NL ;calculationview ; ;comp.prod.global.bol.vertrag.pc.pol;CA_VTRG_NL_STAT ;calculationview ; ; ;0
```

**Each line represents a 1:1 connection between CA_VTRG_NL and a source** (connected via a projection node and following joins) **except for the first line**. The Table is only used by one of the underlying calculation views. All other tables used by an underlying calculation view are not listed.

[image]

​

Comment: What exactly is the question here?

Comment: The question is why is there an entry (first line) with table CUANC_CLNTMAP even though I do not use the table CUANC_CLNTMAP in the calculation view CA_VTRG_NL

Comment: Can you check the view's XML for any reference to the table?

Comment: Yes I checked the XML and will further investigate .. then post the results.

Comment: After 4 years, would you be able to remember if you solved this question? also, any chance that your metadata viz tool is publicly available?